# How to overlay PNG image on top of another wallpaper image?

Tags: windows-7, windows, images, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have several wallpaper images on Windows 7 and I want that my users can choose an image and after they choose, another PNG image will display on top of that image.

Like this:

[image: PNG on top of wallpaper].

Something like that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bginfo.aspx

I think it can be achieved with GPO but I'm not sure.

I run Windows Server 2012.

How can I do that?

Comment: the tools get the desktop handle and write to it. BGinfo works on 2012, but has some limitations. also try this alternative: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bginfo4x/

Comment: a similar solution could allow a picture on tiled wallpaper.

Comment: What similar solution?

Comment: i just checked on my server for that and i only see that you can set A wallpaper but this will overwrite what the user puts on next logon. What you could do is use the tool mentioned above and put that in a hidden shared folder and have a GPO with all users to run it as a logon script.

Comment: Now if you want, you could take it a step further and actually WRITE your own program to do this. Probably C, C++ or C# would be of choice. I think the closest you could get is to display an image with `.5` opacity and have it stay behind all windows at all times.

Comment: sorry if i post too much, just thinking like a programmer. What one could do is have a program that gets the current wallpaper that the user is using upon logon, within the program add a watermark/text overlay and rewrite the image. The current wallpaper filename can be seen from the registry in HKU\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper. Just sharing ideas, maybe you can write a program for this!